# Apache Superset - improve performance

Tags: performance, apache-superset

we are struggling with low performance on Apache Superset.

We are using docker-compose deployment, with default Redis cache and one Celery Worker, and one Celery Beat.

The stack is running on our own hardware, so we can manage "unlimited" resources for our stack.
At this moment we are struggling with very slow UI if all users are using Superset (not much, like 40 users at the same time).

Can you help me, how to get better performance?